# Why is the word "diagonalizes" uses for the Fourier transform of the Laplacian?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

In Tao's Fourier Transform preprint, [https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/fourier.pdf](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/preprints/fourier.pdf), they show explicitly that the Laplacian can be viewed as a Fourier multiplier. In the same paragraph, they write

> ...This identity shows that the Fourier transform *diagonalizes* the
> Laplacian

Why is the word "diagonalizes" used in this context? I know it from a Linear Algebra context, in which we diagonalize some matrix, but in this context it seems out of place. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Read the explanation after the colon, up to the semicolon.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but what you wrote does not help me understand why the word "diagonalizes" is used in this context.

Comment: In linear algebra we learn to diagonalize certain linear operators. It’s the same idea here. The Laplace operator is a linear operator on a certain space of functions. The “Fourier basis” is a “basis” of eigenfunctions for the Laplace operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a Hermitian $n\times n$ matrix $A$. The spectral theorem guarantees the existence of a unitary matrix $U$ such that $A = U\Lambda U^\dagger$ or, equivalently, $\Lambda = U^\dagger AU$, where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of $A$. $A$ is related to a diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ via conjugation by a transformation $U$, so we say that $U$ diagonalizes $A$.

Now consider the Laplacian on some suitable space of functions $\mathcal{U}$ where both the Laplacian and Fourier transform are well-defined as maps from $\mathcal{U}$ to itself. The equation written in the OP says that for any function $u\in\mathcal{U}$, $$\mathcal{F}\Delta u = -4\pi|\xi|^2\mathcal{F}u.$$ Now define $v= \mathcal{F}^{-1}u$ and substitute to obtain $$\left(\mathcal{F}\Delta\mathcal{F}^{-1}\right)v = -4\pi|\xi|^2v.$$ If we now define an operator $\Lambda v := -4\pi|\xi|^2v$, we have $$\left(\mathcal{F}\Delta\mathcal{F}^{-1}\right)v = \Lambda v \quad \forall v\in\mathcal{U}.$$
$\Lambda$ is a diagonal operator because pointwise values if $w = \Lambda v$, when the value of $w$ at a specific point $\xi_0$ depends only on the value of $v$ at $\xi_0$. This is the same as in the finite-dimensional case where a diagonal matrix simple scales each component, except now we have a continuum of components. Now, we can say that we have represented $\Delta$ as a diagonal transformation $\Lambda$ via a similarity transformation $\mathcal{F}$, so we can say that $\mathcal{F}$ diagonalizes $\Delta$.